# How is PHPSESSID cookie being set in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, session, cookie

The only place I could find where the cookie actually not being initialized but renewed on every request is `renewCookie()` function in `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager`. Whenever there is a new session or switch between session for eg. during login the PHPSESSID is not set from `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager`